# Video tearing - Sync between video and frame update

Tags: three.js, html5-video

I am doing a project where I am playing a video texture on a surface while moving a virtual camera in a 3D world.

Its very similar to the https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular

I experience some tearing especially when the video contains movement and I move the virtual camera at the same time. I think its because the video is not fully updated when being rendered.

Is there a way to syncronize the video-texture update and the render update? A callback from the video perhaps.

I am on firefox 55.0.2 64bit on arch linux.

Kind regards

Jesper